# Can we interchange "as" and "which" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

"Memory is also susceptible to them, as is thinking more generally." Can I use "which" instead of "as"? And why?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

- "as is" sets up a comparison, saying that "thinking", as well as "memory", is "susceptible".
- "which is" creates an *independent clause*, thereby *equating* "thinking" with "memory" —not only in regard to being susceptible, but "generally". I don't think that's what was meant (though I can't be sure; you did not include context to identify what "them" refers to.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean "thinking" is a noun in the mentioned sentence?

Comment: Yes. It is a _gerund_ .   http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic "is X, as is Y" makes whatever applies to X also apply to Y.  We're not told what "them" refers to, but suppose that it's stressors.  Then the sentence says that memory (a noun) and general cognitive processes (i.e, "thinking [processes] more generally" (a gerund phrase used as a noun) are both influenced by stress.

If you replace "as" with the relative pronoun "which," you have a clause with an ambiguous parse.  Either

> which (subject) -- is thinking (verb, present progressive tense)

or

> which (subject) -- is (present tense copulative verb) -- thinking
>   (gerund as predicate nominative)

In either case, you've got something represented by the "which" being or doing something, and there must be an antecedent to attach to the "which."  The likely candidate by proximity is the pronoun "them," but that's not possible because "them" is plural and the verb in the clause ("is") is singular.  The only other noun is "Memory," but that makes no sense:  memory isn't thinking more generally, and memory can't do thinking by itself.

This is a long way around to say that your substitution is impossible.